# Is there a "tangent paraboloid" to generalize the tangent plane?

Tags: calculus, geometry

Is there a "tangent (hyper) paraboloid" to generalize the tangent plane to higher-order terms? Or something like that?

I'm thinking in terms of the Taylor expansion of a function $f: x \longmapsto f(x)$ at a point $a \in \text{Dom}(f)$, where $\text{Dom}(f)$ is the domain of the function $f$.

In other words, if the tangent (hyper) plane is the first-order, linear, "flat" approximation to some (hyper) surface (or, as I like to think of, the space of (first-order, linear) infinitesimal displacements, or just the space of (first-order, linear) infinitesimals), are there generalizations to higher-order, curved approximations (perhaps coming from the Taylor expansion itself)?

Comment: Indeed, Taylor's theorem is generalizable to higher dimensions: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#Taylor's_theorem_for_multivariate_functions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can certainly do that, but the result is less meaningful (and has less intuitive explanatory power) than osculating circles for curves.  Because of invariance under rotations and by implicit function theorem, we can assume that the surface is locally the graph $z=f(x,y)$ of a function $f(x,y)$ at a critical point.  Then the second-order Taylor term of $f$ will give a paraboloid $z=ax^2+2bxy+cy^2$ which will be an elliptic paraboloid, hyperbolic paraboloid, or more degenerate surface which is the best second-order approximation to the surface near that point.